# Video: from bits to video

Tags: video, udp, video-streaming, media-player

I was wondering if anyone knew of any books which explain the very basics of video processing. From the bytes on the wire to the video on the player, I just don't understand how it all works. When does a muxer come into the chain of events? Does a codec come before muxing? Are there any books that teach this sort of stuff? Even better are there books that teach with sample code?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- [Video demystified: a handbook for the digital engineer](http://books.google.com.ua/books*/about/Video_demystified.html?id=n2qjjvcBdrUC&redir_esc=y) by Keith Jack
- [Programming Microsoft DirectShow for digital video and televisión](http://books.google.com.ua/books/about/Programming_Microsoft_DirectShow_for_dig.html?id=VJlobjl6xAIC&redir_esc=y) by Mark Pesce, see related books there such as [Fundamentals of Audio and Video Programming for Games](http://books.google.com.ua/books?id=_oVGAAAAYAAJ&hl=uk&source=gbs_similarbooks)
- [Programming Cameras and Pan-Tilts: with DirectX and Java](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1558607560) - not perhaps a direct answer to your question, but guides through writing "some video code" in detail

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question. I briefly saw Video demystified and it seems that's what I need. I can't thank you enough for suggesting these books.